# Angular Bind arabic letters on english keyboard

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-material, keyboard, key-bindings

I need to bind arabic characters on the layout of english keyboard When a user types on input the arabic characters should be displayed dynamically on input. It should not be like a virtual keyboard.

I tried some libraries and other ways , everything is showing  virtual keyboard and etc.

Comment: I think remember in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75362220/using-replace-and-position-setters-not-working-properly/75362755#75362755) someone made a question looks like close that your problem

Comment: Did you have any idea about any npm packages that do the same?I just searched a lot but nothing is working properly.